# How can I avoid unnecessarily checking the same if-statement in my while loop?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, k-means

I want to implement k-means clustering in MATLAB and at the moment I have a function that looks like this:

```
function clusters = kmeans(k, data, measure)
...
iterate = true;
while (iterate)
    ...
    if(strcmp(measure, "euclidean")
        dists = getEuclideanDists(centroids, data)
    elseif(strcmp(measure, "pearson")
        dists = getModifiedPearson(centroids, data)
    end
    ...
end
end
```

I only need to check what the string `measure` is equal to once, but I need the body of the if-statement in the while loop because the value of `centroids` changes during the while loops, and in turn, so does `dist`. Is there a more efficient way of making the check just once but continuously updating the value of `dist`?

Also is there a 1-liner / function that I can use to calculate the Pearson Correlation Coefficient of each row in my dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) before the loop based on the comparison:

```
function clusters = kmeans(k, data, measure)
    ...
    if(strcmp(measure, "euclidean")
        getDists = @getEuclideanDists;
    elseif(strcmp(measure, "pearson")
        getDists = @getModifiedPearson;
    end

    iterate = true;
    while (iterate)
        ...
        dists = getDists(centroids, data);
        ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either simplify the test:

```
douec = strcmp(measure, "euclidean");
dopea = strcmp(measure, "pearson");
while (iterate)
    ...
    if (doeuc) {
        dists = getEuclideanDists(centroids, data)
    elseif (dopea) {
        dists = getModifiedPearson(centroids, data)
    end
    ...
end
```

or make two loops:

```
if (strcmp(measure, "euclidean")) {
   while (iterate) ...
}
if (strcmp(measure, "pearson")) {
   while (iterate) ...
}
```

BTW, not sure your use of strcmp is what you want.

Also, if ueclidean and pearson are are the only 2 possibilities then a simple (if-else) is sufficient (no need for the elseif's compare).

Comment: If I use two loops I will have practically the same code written twice which doesn't seem like a good approach. I want efficiency in both writing and executing the actual code. Are there any other alternatives or is there just no way around it?

Comment: Unless matlab supports function pointers, I think those are your alternatives.  In any event, unless testing has revealed an actual need for optimization, my opinion is just write the clearest, simplest code you can.